# Congrats and Thanks to Jonas Meyer!

Tags: discussion, bounty, specific-user, celebration

Unless I am mistaken [Jonas Meyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1424/jonas-meyer?tab=bounties&sort=offered) just became the first member to have offered bounties in excess of 10000 points.

### Congrats and Thanks to a most generous benefactor!

In order to turn this into a question I'm also soliciting opinions on whether a related badge would be a good idea.

---

Update: Jonas Meyer is nowadays over 25k. Alexander Gruber and Vladimir Reshitnikov are the other members of the 10k club.

Comment: Other active benefactors include

 - Alexander Gruber at 6400 
 - Byron Schmuland  at 5100
Please add any +5000 donor I missed

Comment: Something to help: http://data.stackexchange.com/math/revision/209184/272413/top-20-most-generous-users-bounties-awarded-in-total

Comment: Thanks, Asaf. So I missed math110 at 8400. I apologize.

Comment: Note that math110 gave over 100 different bounties.

Comment: A badge like *Financier*, *Sponsor*, *Patron* or, if we want to go into classics, *Maecenas*?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I am so eager to do what he's been doing here too. :-)

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It just occurred to me that instead of bumping this closed thread I should have posted my update in your chatroom dedicated to listing milestones achieved by users. What do you think about including this type celebrations there? May be you already have (sorry I lost the link to that chatroom, when my laptop crashed).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The room [is here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/17403). (Actually, it is linked in several celebration-related posts here on meta.) Almost nobody posts there, so any kind of interesting stats related to this site is more than welcome - at least I won't just speak to myself there all the time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thank you.

I am ambivalent on the badge idea.  I am among those who already find sufficient motivation to offer bounties, and I don't know what positive or negative effects such a badge might have.  Here is a related thread on meta.stackexchange.com:

[Badge for bounties offered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/badge-for-bounties-offered)

Comment: [We don't need badges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges) to tell you are a gentleman and a scholar!